# Soundfile library, amplitude range when reading files

Tags: python, signal-processing, normalization

I am using the library Soundfile (which uses the library libsndfile) for digital sound processing. It has a function for reading audio files, soundfile.read(). Which can be used like this:

```
import soundfile as sf
input_file, sampling_rate_orig = sf.read(Path)
```

The output samples of the audio files are mapped to the (-1,1) range, and my two questions are:

**1) What sort of scale/normalization is applied to get this mapping?**

**2) Why some samples are allowed to exceed this limit?**

To explain 2): When reading 60 different audio files of 3 seconds duration and with sampling rate of 22050 Hz, out of the 3969000 (60*3*22050) total samples, 51 samples had a value greater than 1. The same happens for the negative limit. 36 samples are smaller than -1 then.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Okey, @bastibe the owner of the Soundfile repository on Github has answered this question for me in a precise and clear way. 
Here is the link for the thread:

https://github.com/bastibe/SoundFile/issues/226